# How to know if there are other paths than a given path?

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

Is it possible to know with JSONPath that **other** "paths" exist?

By an existing "path" I mean a string in the form "a.b.c" or "a.b.d" like for this JSON:

```
{
  'a' : {
      'b' : [ { 'c' : 0 }, { 'd': 1 ]
  } 
 }
```

Can a JSONPath be written to tell if there any **other** "paths" other then a.b.c and a.b.d ?

For example in the following JSON, it should find that there is the property 'e':

```
{
  'a' : {
      'b' : [ { 'c' : 0 }, { 'd': 1 ],
      'e': 2
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Both json are not valid. Kindly edit the post to include valid json.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve but if this gets more complicated you probably want to think about JSON Schema validation. Here is an example: https://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on JSONPath Implementation. The jsonpath options have a setting to output the path or value.

**JSONPATH**

```
 $..*
```

**All possible Output Paths**

```
[
  "$['a']",
  "$['a']['b']",
  "$['a']['e']",
  "$['a']['b'][0]",
  "$['a']['b'][1]",
  "$['a']['b'][0]['c']",
  "$['a']['b'][1]['d']"
]
```

Tool : https://jsonpath.com/
Checkbox Option : Output paths

[image]

Tool : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/
Checkbox option : Normalized path expressions

[image]

Comment: `$['a']['e']` is equivalent to `$.a.e`